# Unable to renew the user profile for key: KeycloakOidcClient: Bad token response, error=invalid_grant, description=Token is not active

Tags: pac4j

I´m using pac4j, shiro with Keycloak.

I´m getting the following error message:

```
Unable to renew the user profile for key: KeycloakOidcClient: org.pac4j.core.exception.TechnicalException: Bad token response, error=invalid_grant, description=Token is not active
```

The error message occurs as soon my session has been expired and I would like to use again my Webapp. It´s raised in this class from Pac4j:
org.pac4j.oidc.credentials.authenticator.OidcAuthenticator.executeTokenRequest(OidcAuthenticator.java:206)

Shiro.ini

```
#Keycloack
oidcConfig = org.pac4j.oidc.config.KeycloakOidcConfiguration
oidcConfig.realm = gixx
oidcConfig.baseUri = http://localhost:9009/auth
oidcConfig.discoveryURI = http://localhost:9009/auth/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration
oidcConfig.clientId = myclient
oidcConfig.secret = xasasasasasasassasa
oidcConfig.clientAuthenticationMethodAsString = client_secret_basic
oidcConfig.useNonce = true
oidcConfig.scope = openid
oidcConfig.responseType = code
oidcConfig.withState = false
```

Where do I define the session expired time? Is this defined in Keycloak?
Or do I use here also Shiro:

```
# Session Timeout 8 hours
sessionManager.globalSessionTimeout= 28800000
```

Answer (score 0):

On every request, pac4j checks if the profile is expired and if so, tries to renew it.

You should have a shorter web session than the lifetime of the pac4j profile = the access token lifetime.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Where do I define those values? In Shiro.ini, in Keycloak?

Comment: In shiro.ini, it's the web session timeout

Comment: what are you prefer? In Keycloak config I have: Access Token Lifespan = 5 Minutes. So I will set this to 1 hour and in shiro.ini also tosessionManager.globalSessionTimeout= 3600000 ?

Comment: also sometimes I got this error: Bad token response, error=invalid_grant, description=PKCE code verifier not specified

Comment: Yes, you should set a smaller timeout for your web session < 1 hour. If PKCE is an issue, you may want to disable it on client side : `config.disablePkce=true`